# Symfony EasyAdmin AssociationField Many-to-Many autocomplete not working

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, easyadmin, symfony6

I have an entity called `Work` which has a many-to-many relationship with the entity `Author`. I used EasyAdmin 4 with Symfony 6 to create a `WorkCrudController` where I use an `AssociationField` to assign multiple authors to a work. If I don't use `autocomplete()` it works as expected, but when using it, it shows only the current author, which is quite weird. Checking the debug tab, I noticed that the query is fixing the author `id` and the event `id` **(!)**, which is quite weird. Ok, the user register in an event, and the work is then included in the area of the event, but the only configuration I do is:

```php
public function createIndexQueryBuilder(SearchDto $searchDto, EntityDto $entityDto, FieldCollection $fields, FilterCollection $filters): QueryBuilder
{
    return parent::createIndexQueryBuilder($searchDto, $entityDto, $fields, $filters)
        ->innerJoin('entity.area', 'a')
        ->innerJoin('entity.authors', 't')
        ->andWhere('a.event = :event')
        ->andWhere('t.user = :user')
        ->setParameter('event', $this->event->getId())
        ->setParameter('user', $this->getUser()->getId())
    ;
}
```

And the field creation:

```php
yield AssociationField::new('authors', 'works.authors')->autocomplete()->onlyOnForms()
    ->setHelp('<a href="' . $insert_author_url . '" target="_blank">' . $insert_author_label . '</a>')
    ->setQueryBuilder(fn (QueryBuilder $queryBuilder) =>
        $queryBuilder->addOrderBy('entity.name', 'ASC')
    )
;
```

Here is the query when I search for `asdasdas`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT a0_.id AS id_0 FROM author a0_ INNER JOIN author_event a2_ ON a0_.id = a2_.author_id INNER JOIN event e1_ ON e1_.id = a2_.event_id WHERE (LOWER(a0_.name) LIKE ? OR LOWER(a0_.institution) LIKE ? OR LOWER(a0_.email) LIKE ?) AND a0_.id = ? AND e1_.id = ? LIMIT 20
Parameters:
[▼
  "%asdasdas%"
  "%asdasdas%"
  "%asdasdas%"
  1
  1
]
```

I don't understand why the query joins with author_event and event, if I don't specify any relation in the field. It sure looks like a bug since when I remove `autocomplete()` it works perfectly...